# popmotion tween filter for unique number count

Tags: javascript, tween, popmotion

I'm trying to use a tween as a counter that only returns 0-4 over a duration. 
I only want it to return a number of the same once. 
I'm using https://popmotion.io/. Here is what I have so far.

```
  import { tween, easing, transform } from 'popmotion';

  onHandleClick() {
   // const { clamp } = transform;
    const twn = tween({ from: 0, to: 4 }).pipe(Math.round);
    twn.start(this.addToList);
  }

  addToList(val) {
    console.log('val = ', val);
 }
```

The above outputs the following:

```
val =  1
val =  1
val =  2
val =  2
val =  2
val =  3
val =  3
val =  3
val =  3
val =  3
val =  4
val =  4
val =  4
val =  4
val =  4
val =  4
val =  4
```

What I'm after is so it only outputs a unique number from 0 - 4 
Example:

```
val =  0
val =  1
val =  2
val =  3
val =  4
```

They have a filter method that it says.

> filter((v: any) => boolean): Returns a new action that filters out
>   values when the provided function returns false.

I'm not sure how I would use the filter to only return the same number once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Popmotion tween API](https://popmotion.io/api/tween/) returns filter, while, start and pipe, where each of them is actually an iterator function. So the values before passing to start.update will be passed to those iterator functions one by one. Which means initially (before animation starts) you cannot get all the values that will passed to start.update.

Which leaves no option than to have a global state (i.e., state above popmotion.tween) like a variable to store lastValue. Then update the lastValue in every start.update and filter if current updateValue is same as lastValue. Let's see the code, it will be more easy to understand

```
var lastValue;

popmotion.tween({from:0,to:4})
            .pipe(Math.round)
            .filter(function(value){
                return lastValue != value;
             })
            .start(function(updateValue){
                lastValue = updateValue;
                console.log('val = ',updateValue)
             })
```

In the above code, Tween values are piped for rounding, then filtered by comparing with lastValue (a state which is global for tween). And on every update this global state(lastValue) is changed. It is important to notice that you should round the values(pipe) before filtering it.

Output:

```
val =  0
val =  1
val =  2
val =  3
val =  4
```

Well you where very close to the solution, using filter to solve it.

In case you are not aware of how filter works, basically if the iterator function returns true for a value passed, the value is accepted and stored in a separate array, and if false is returned the value passed is rejected and not stored. So at the end of the filter you are left with a new array containing all the values which made the filter iterator function return true. You can read more about filters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ah thanks Ankit Kumar Ojha. Shame you have to save a global but I get what you are saying you need something to save the lastValue to compare it with. This is what I was trying to avoid but seeing your code and the more I think about it you have o have something to compare it to. I'm wondering can you pass a object to the tween like TweenMax allows. Something like tween({:count: 0}, {from:0,to:4}) then the tween would update the count in the object.